# React Js setState

Tags: reactjs

I'm stuck in setState. I'm submitting the form and sending the data via ajax call. In return I'm getting the response data and wanted to store the value in setState and print it in UI. But I'm not able to store it properly. I'm not able to understand where I'm going wrong.

Here is the code below :

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      res : "",
      month : "",
      day : "",
      year : ""
    }
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = this.input.value;
    var parent = this;

    $.ajax({
      url: '/url',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          month: this.state.month,
          day: this.state.day,
          year: this.state.year
      },
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(data) // Here I'm getting correct response.. 
          parent.setState({res: data.res});
      }.bind(this),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" ref={(input) => this.input = input} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <div id="res">
            {this.state.res} // The value is not printing here.. 
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the result of data.res

Comment: the response data from ajax call.. data.res is giving me accepted result

Comment: I meant what is its value, Is it an object, array or a string

Comment: It's a string value

Comment: Try this and let me know the output of console.log() , `success: function(data) {
          console.log(data) // Here I'm getting correct response.. 
          this.setState({res: data.res}, function(){ console.log(this.state.res)});
      }.bind(this)`

Comment: okay 2min wil let you know

Comment: Is it possible that `<div id="res">` is hidden with CSS.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri console.log in both the side it giving the correct value. I'm able to access the **this.setstate.res** here but not outside ajax call

Comment: If you are getting in setState callback you should get it in render, try console.log(this.state.res) in the render  method too. If it works there too, then either your res is not a string or your div is hidden

Comment: @B77 what is the output of `this.state.res`. I guess response  is HTML string. .

Comment: @Ved it's string output.

Comment: It shouldn't be `this.setstate.res` , but `this.state.res`

Comment: @shubham, I tried console.log in render but I'm not getting any value.. and also the div is visible bcz I'm printing some other UI stuff over there..

Comment: can you post the output. There is no other reason I see.

Comment: **so my mistake while replying**. yes it's this.state.res

Comment: Is your page refreshing somehow, In your code you have used event.preventDefault but is it possible from somewhere else

Comment: yes I tried even that. it's not refreshing at all..

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks a lot for your reply. I got it solved. I added shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) { return true; }

Comment: @B77 noops `shouldComponentUpdate` should not be the reason . by deafult ut returns true

Comment: It should have worked without it too. Since default behaviour is to update on any state change

Comment: I tried your code with a GET request. It seems to be working fine. You can look over here: https://codesandbox.io/s/QWZZ4nqxY